# HTML issue with Divs in Form?

Tags: html

When I put this in JsFiddle, the closing tag of the form and the two closing tags of the divs in the form are both red in my fiddle which seems to indicate that something is wrong. When I put it in w3.orgs validator, it gave errors on those. The errors were

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
<link type="text/css" style="stylesheet" src="first.css">
    <h1>Great Master</h1>
    <div id="hello">
        <div>We like destroying satan beards</div>
        <div>We want home</div>
    </div>

    <aside id="list">
        <div><strong>Super Fun</strong></div>
        <ul>

            <li>I love fun</li>
            <li>This is Great</li>

        </ul>
    </aside>

    <form>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="happy">
        <aside id="happy"> Put a number in here to check if it is happy.</aside>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="perfect">
        <aside id="perfect"> Die </aside>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
```

The Errors from W3.org were

```
Error Line 3, Column 6: Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.
<body>
Content model for element head:
If the document is an iframe srcdoc document or if title information is available from a higher-level protocol: Zero or more elements of metadata content, of which no more than one is a title element and no more than one is a base element.
Otherwise: One or more elements of metadata content, of which exactly one is a title element and no more than one is a base element.
Error Line 12, Column 17: Element div not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
            <div><strong>Super Fun</strong></div>
Contexts in which element div may be used:
Where flow content is expected.
Content model for element ul:
Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.
Error Line 20, Column 6: Stray start tag form.
<form>
```

**Edit**

ok, I've made some changes to my HTML. but I am still getting the erros about the stray start tag form.

Answer (score 0):

It tells your right there in the output from W3: No `div` in `li`.
And your second form is not within `body`.

Also you're missing `head` with included `title` tags for a complete HTML page.

Comment: There is only one form. and the whole thing is outside of body. Is that an issue?

Comment: @ChrisJones Yes, I just noticed there is only one form. And yes, that is a **big** issue, nothing should be outside of the body, except for the head.

Comment: oh... I must have missed that.. oops. Although I can't think that I've done that before.

Comment: Also, you cannot have a `<div>` in a `<ul>`. `<ul>` expects all its children to be `<li>`. You can put the `<div>` in the `<li>` if you really want, but I don't know why you would to that. That's redundant markup, and terrible style.

Comment: This is mostly just trying some things out here and there. However, I've since changed that. as well as the other thing.

Comment: I've made those changes and still getting an error.

Comment: I don't believe you're getting the same errors. Got an updated example?

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters you cant have the div elements within the lists.

Comment: So is the issue that I have the div inside the list but it isn't a li?